# Ajax data posted to php returning null

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a form on a website setup to take various details from a user. Name, address, etc. I am using jQuery and ajax to post the data to then be emailed to the website owners using PHP.

I am using a for each loop to loop through p tags in the form and then add that data to an array. If the p tag has an id "required" and the value is empty then the loop breaks and displays a message to fill in that value.

I have determined it is something within the loop that is causing a problem, as if I change the loop to just add a generic value for each input it finds then the data posts successfully. I'm just not sure what could be the problem.

Here is the jQuery:

```
$("#requestForm input[type='submit']").click(function() {
    event.preventDefault();

    var formData = [];
    var allowSubmit;

    $("#requestForm > div > p:not(.ignore)").each(function() {            
        if($(this).children("input[type='text']").length > 0) {
            var input = $(this).find("input[type='text']").first();
        }
        else if($(this).children("input[type='checkbox']").length > 0) {
            var input = $(this).children("input[type='checkbox']").first();
        }
        else if($(this).children("select").length > 0) {
            var input = $(this).children("select").first();
        }
        else if($(this).children("textarea").length > 0) {
            var input = $(this).children("textarea").first();
        }
        else {
            var input = null;
        }

        if(input != null) {
            if($(this).attr("id") == "required" && (input.val() == "" || input.val() == null)) {
                $("#message").text($(this).children("label").text() + " is required");

                allowSubmit = false;
                return false;
            }
            else {
                if (input.attr("type") == "checkbox") {
                    if(input.is(":checked")) {
                        formData[input.attr("name")] = "Yes";
                    }
                    else {
                        formData[input.attr("name")] = "No";
                    }
                }
                else {
                    $("#message").text("");

                    formData[$(this).children("label").text()] = input.val();
                }

                allowSubmit = true;
            }
        }
    });

    if(allowSubmit == false) {
        return;
    }

    console.log(formData);

    $.ajax({
        url: root_dir + "scripts/sendBrochureRequest.php",
        method: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: ({formData}),
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

At the minute all the PHP does is echo json_encode($_POST['formData']); So that I can see if anything is being received.

When ajax returns a value it is whatever the formData array is initially set to, so it isn't picking up the data being added to the array by the loop. If I set formData to any other value, then ajax returns this set value.

Comment: You're not sending a 'formdata' argument to PHP. Your data is an array of values. My first thought is that this is massively over-complicated when you could just do `$("#requestForm').serialize()` to get the form content. I can see you're ignoring some fields too, but that's easy to achieve with serialisation as well.

Comment: That is just what I have chosen to call the array variable. Could that be causing a problem, is PHP expecting to see a formdata object?

Comment: Yes, because your code tells it to expect one: `$_POST['formData']`

Comment: I agree with @RoryMcCrossan about the complication. You can easily edit the serialized form if you want to. Though, you should really set up your html to return the desired format from the start.

Comment: Try `data: {"formData": formData}` in the AJAX. But then you might have to decode the contents of the $_POST variable. It's probably not straightforward. As the other say, you appear to have massively overcomplicated this on the client side, although without seeing the source HTML it's hard to be completely sure.

Comment: I have opted to go with serializing the data, which is significantly simpler and working correctly now. I wasn't aware of this before. Thanks